# For and foreach loop generating correct indexes on count

Tags: php, function, for-loop, foreach, woocommerce

Context:
Have 2 products, product 1 has quantity of 5, product 2 has quantity of 4.
I am trying to build a loop so that it creates data, for each quantity, however I am get 18 entries instead of 9.

```
 $count = 9;
 $items = $order->get_items();
 for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
    foreach ($items as $item) { 
        do_action();
    }
 }
```

however I need the set form to run for the amount of count which is the overall quantity, but I need the $item, not $items. So product 1 would iterate the do_action() * 5 times and product 2 would iterate do_action 4 times. 
I hope this makes sense.

Edit: - the get_items() comes from woocommerce hook

Comment: I think you didn't provide enough informations... and neither enough code...

Comment: please show more code, not only pseudo code. When do you populate `$items` or when does it change? And what exactly means _"I am having no luck"_? What is the output/behaviour right now?

Comment: What is the use of `$count = 9` and `for loop`? You want the loop to be dynamic as per the `quantity` of each product in each order then why hard code `count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your notes correctly I believe you need to rearrange your for loops so that for each is around the for loop.

foreach(item...
   for(I ...

Comment: Please format the code above. Select the code and then use *code formatting* button from *formatting toolbar*.